# How to group results by intervals with condition

Tags: colors, spotfire, tibco, calculation

G-Green  A-Amber R-Red

If the value is less than 8 it should be Red between 8 and 9 it should be Amber and above 9 it's green.

Also I need to group the result, for eg : if  the Result is GAR (Green, Amber and Red) i need a value as "Not Good" and if the value is RAG(Red Amber and Green) it should be "Good" and if it is all Red it is "Poor"

How can I group the Red, Amber and Green?

```
+---------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| PROJECT | SUBTASK | TASK | PERIOD | VALUE |
+---------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| A       | AA      | AAA  |      1 |     6 |
| A       | AA      | AAA  |      2 |    8.2|
| A       | AA      | AAA  |      3 |    10 |
| B       | BB      | BBB  |      1 |    10 |
| B       | BB      | BBB  |      2 |     9 |
| B       | BB      | BBB  |      3 |     6 |
| C       | CC      | CCC  |      1 |     7 |
| C       | CC      | CCC  |      2 |     7 |
| C       | CC      | CCC  |      3 |     6 |
+---------+---------+------+--------+-------+
```

Output

```
+---------+---------+------+---+---+---+
| PROJECT | SUBTASK | TASK | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---------+---------+------+---+---+---+
| A       | AA      | AAA  | R | A | G |
| B       | BB      | BBB  | G | G | R |
| C       | CC      | CCC  | R | R | R |
+---------+---------+------+---+---+---+
```

Final Output

```
+---------+---------+------+----------+
| PROJECT | SUBTASK | TASK |  Result  |
+---------+---------+------+----------+
| A       | AA      | AAA  | Good |
| B       | BB      | BBB  | Not Good |
| C       | CC      | CCC  | Poor     |
+---------+---------+------+----------+
```

Comment: how did you get red for project A when there is no value < 8? There is no integer between 8 and 9... so what do you mean?

Comment: @scsimon. Sorry, i have corrected the table now. have added value between 8-9

Comment: Thanks for the edit @BULB   See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the edited sample data, the rule should be if it is >= 9 versus > 9. With that in mind here are the steps

Insert a calculated column and name it `[CalcCol]`

```
case  
when [VALUE]<8 then "R" 
when ([VALUE]>=8) and ([VALUE]<9) then "A" 
when [VALUE]>=9 then "G"
end
```

Insert a calculated column and name it `[Concat]`

```
Substitute(Substitute(Concatenate([CalcCol]) over (Intersect([PROJECT],[SUBTASK],[TASK])),",","")," ","")
```

Insert a calculated column and name it `[FinalOutput]`

```
case  
when [Concat]="RAG" then "Good" 
when [Concat]="GGR" then "Not Good" 
when [Concat]="RRR" then "Poor"
end
```

Now, you will see your results in a regular table view, or in a cross table view with `Max([FinalOutput])` as the Cell values and the vertical axis set to Project, Subtask, Task in this order.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks so much @scsimon. I got the result as expected. Great help!